# How to ban 250.000 IP ranges?

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, firewall

I am using iblocklist.com and I want to ban a list of IPs I made from accessing my web server on a CentOS dedi.

I have a bash script that can parse it and add the ranges one by one to iptables.
My issues are:

- It takes way too long. Anyway to speed up the processes?
- Will iptables even be able to handle this kind of load?

Thanks

Comment: It seems like it'd be shorter to white list at this point... :P

Comment: 250,000 addresses? I hope that that server is not running anything *other* than iptables.

Comment: apparently you don't control the router for this server, or you could nullroute them all...

Answer (score 9):

If you really have 250,000 addresses, you shouldn't be using individual iptables rules.  Instead you should probably be using an [ipset](http://ipset.netfilter.org/).  An ipset uses a hashtable and is far more efficient for this purpose.